# Diophantine equation $a^2+b^2+c^2=a^2b^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

I am trying to find all non trivial integers for which $a^2+b^2+c^2=a^2b^2$.
As suggested I have tried working (mod 4).

This is what I've gotten so far:
Squares can have a remainder of 0 or 1 (mod 4).
So the rhs can be 0 or 1 (mod 4). It is 1 if and only if both $a^2$ and $b^2$ have remainder 1 (mod 4).

But if both $a^2$ and $b^2$ are 1 the lhs has remainder 2 or 3 (if $c^2$ also has remainder 1), a contradiction.

So $a^2,b^2$ and $c^2$ must be divisible by 4.
Is this reasoning correct? If I have made any mistakes please let me know.

Comment: Hint:  work $\pmod 4$.

Comment: Severen. there is an interesting problem buried in your question, but I want to draw your attention to [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619), aimed primarily for new users such as yourself. Please study that, and try to improve your question. You can, for example, tell us what you can do with Lulu's hint.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, as you might have noticed this is the first question I have posted. I will try to improve and @lulu thank you for the hint.

Comment: $(a^2-1)(b^2-1)=c^2+1$ also works well $\pmod 3$

Comment: I have voted to reopen as OP has now provided their attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just work from parity.

If $a,b$ are both odd then $a^2+b^2\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $a^2b^2\equiv 1 \pmod 4$  This would mean that $c^2\equiv -1\pmod 4$ which is impossible.

If $a=2A$ and $b$ is odd then we get $1+c^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$ which is, again, impossible.

If $a,b$ are both even then $c$ is also even. Writing them as $2A,2B,2C$ we deduce that $$A^2+B^2+C^2=4A^2B^2$$

As before:  if $A,B$ are both odd then we get $C^2\equiv 2\pmod 4$, which is impossible.  If $A$ is even and $B$ is odd we get $C^2\equiv -1\pmod 4$ which is impossible.  Hence, again, $A,B$ are both even.  This repeats (with higher powers of $2$ appearing on the right) so infinite descent finishes the job.

Comment: The equation is not homogeneous.  So, I don't think the "minimal triple" assumption is a good assumption.

Comment: @Batominovski  Good point.

Comment: Edited.  The modified proof, by descent, should hold.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to prove via the infinite descent method (i.e., showing that $a$, $b$, and $c$ is divisible by $2^k$ for each $k=1,2,\ldots$).  I am offering an alternative solution.

Without loss of generality, suppose that $a\neq 0$.  It can be easily seen that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are even.  Furthermore, we have  $$\left(a^2-1\right)\left(b^2-1\right)=c^2+1\,.$$
Since $a^2-1$ is a natural number congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, it has a prime divisor $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.  However, this means $c^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, and we know that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: Thank you I like your answer, when I tried the exercise again I also thought of using proof by infinite descent.